# Check whether list of dataframe

Tags: r

I want to check whether input data is dataframe or list of dataframe. I have function which checks dataframe or tibble. How to extend it to check if list containig dataframes. If list contains vectors it should return FALSE

```
 check.class <- function(x) { inherits(x, c("data.frame", "tbl_df"))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
check.class <- function(x) { inherits(x, c("data.frame", "tbl_df"))}

check.list.of.dataframes <- function(x){
  is.list(x) && all(sapply(x, check.class))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
mylist <- list(df = data.frame(c1 = 1:5, c2 = 6:10), c(1:3))
mylist
$df
  c1 c2
1  1  6
2  2  7
3  3  8
4  4  9
5  5 10

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

all(sapply(mylist, is.list))
[1] FALSE
```